# How to define the canonical sheaf on singular varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a variety which might be singular, how to defined the canonical sheaf $K_X$ on $X$?

When $X$ is a proper, irreducible variety over $\mathbb{C}$, Ueno defined $K_X$ as the pushforward of the canonical sheaf of its nonsigular model (see Chapter2 in his book " Classification Theory of Algebraic Varieties and Compact Complex Spaces"). However, I was wondering if there is a well-defined canonical sheaf on singular variety which is not proper (over $\mathbb{C}$ is OK for me). I will be very appreciated if someone can point out referenced of this kind.

Comment: You can find it in page 8 of the book singularities of minimal model program of Kollar

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For $X$ normal, saying that canonical divisor is the pushforward of the canonical divisor of a resolution of singularities is totally fine (it even works in characteristic $p > 0$ if you happen to have a resolution).  In particular, if $\pi : Y \to X$ is a resolution of singularities, then $\pi_* K_Y$ is $K_X$ (here we define $\pi_* K_Y$ by simply throwing away any components of $K_Y$ that get contracted to non-divisorial varieties).

**However:**  The pushforward of the canonical *sheaf* $\omega_Y$ is not the canonical sheaf $\omega_X$ in general.  Indeed, $\pi_* \omega_Y = \omega_X$ is very close to requiring that $X$ has *rational singularities.*  (Actually one definition of rational singularities, typically attributed to Kempf, is that $X$ is Cohen-Macaulay and $\pi_* \omega_Y = \omega_X$.

A good exercise is to show that if $X = \text{Spec} k[x,y,z]/(x^3+y^3+z^3)$ and $\pi : Y \to X$ is the blowup of the cone point, then $\pi_* \omega_Y = \mathfrak{m} \cdot \omega_X$ where $\mathfrak{m}$ is the maximal ideal of the origin.  (*Hint:*  use the adjunction formula and the formula for the canonical divisor when blowing up a point on $\mathbb{A}^3$).

### The canonical sheaf

Ok, so what is the right definition of the sheaf $\omega_X$ in general?

Well, for a projective variety of dimension $d$, $i : X \hookrightarrow  \mathbb{P}^N$, define
$$i_* \omega_X := \text{Ext}^{N-d}\big(i_* O_X, O_{\mathbb{P}^N}(-N-1)\big).$$  Since $i$ is a closed embedding, this uniquely determines $\omega_X$.
For $X$ quasi-projective, you can define this by localizing.  There are generalizations which apply to other schemes of finite type over $k$ defined using the $f^!$ functor for $f : X \to k$ the structural map, but I won't get into that here.

### The canonical sheaf is S2

It turns out that for any variety, $\omega_X$ is an S2 sheaf, this means it satisfies Hartog's phenomena (search math overflow).  In particular, the sheaf is determined by its codimension-1 behavior.  There's an easy way to see this, it turns out that if $h : X \to Z = \mathbb{P^d}$ is a generic projection to a hyperplane of the same dimension, then 
$$h_* \omega_X = \text{Hom}(h_* O_X, O_Z(-d-1)).$$
Now, it easily follows that this sheaf is S2 since it is reflexive on $Z$ and reflexive sheaves on $Z$ are always S2 (see for example Hartshorne's *Generalized divisors on Gorenstein schemes*).

Why does this matter?  Well it means that if $U$ is the regular locus of $X$, and furthermore $X \setminus U$ has codimension 2 on $X$ (which happens for example if $X$ is normal), then if $j : U \hookrightarrow X$ is the inclusion, then $j_* \omega_U = \omega_X$ since both sheaves are S2 and they agree outside a codimension-2 set.

### Back to divisors

This also explains our first statement about divisors.  Indeed, any divisor, like $\pi_* K_Y$ is determined outside a codimension 2 set, it is determined on $U$ in fact.  And so if $X$ is normal, $\pi : Y \to X$ is an isomorphism outside of a codimension-2 set of $X$, and so the canonical divisor on that set works fine as a canonical divisor everywhere.  In particular, it can be computed on $Y$ as claimed.

For non-normal $Y$, something can be done, but the formula isn't quite so simple (you also have to describe by what exactly you mean by a divisor on a non-normal variety).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, when $X$ is normal, one can defined the canonical divisor on its smooth locus, and then pullback to $X$. This is explained in the book Toric variety by Cox etc. But in my case, the singularity is worse than that, I hope something can be said when the scheme is Cohen-Macaulay. My original problem is to do adjunction formula on such scheme, and it is mention in the book Birational geometry of algebraic varieties (Page182, Prop5.73) one has adjuntion formula on CM-scheme, but I do not know how could one define $K$ in this setting. Beside, is $\omega_X$ dualizing sheaf?

Comment: Indeed, if $X$ is Cohen-Macaulay, then $\omega_X$ is the dualizing sheaf.  But the canonical sheaf is still defined by the same Ext formula even for non-Cohen-Macaulay schemes.  If your singularity is regular in codimension-1, then you can still use the pushforward from the regular locus.

What exactly is your adjunction problem?  Maybe it would be better to state that.

Comment: Oh, let me explain this perhaps in a better way.  Every integral scheme is S1, and hence Cohen-Macaulay outside a set of codimension 2.  Thus for some purposes you can just work on the Cohen-Macaulay locus.

Comment: (1)In your definition of $K_X$, do you require $X$ to be projective? Moreover, I do not understand the difference between $K_X$ and $\omega_X$. (2)My adjunction problem is: $X$ is a normal, Cohen-Macaulay variety with anticanonical sheaf $−K_X=D_1+\dots +D_n$, where $D_i$ are effective Cartier divisors. Suppose $Y$ is a complete intersection of $D_i′s$. I want to use adjunction formula to show $K_Y=0$. By doing adjunction formula as in Birational geometry of algebraic varieties (Page182, Prop5.73) for each complete intersection ,

Comment: con't, and the complete intersection preserve the CM-condition, the result can be proved. But the first thing confused me is the meaning of $K_X,K_Y$. 

Comment: To me, $K_X$ is a divisor, $\omega_X$ is a sheaf, $\omega_X \cong O_X(K_X)$.  This is probably the most common convention in birational geometry but not the only one.  For your problem, let me give you a hint: do it one $D_i$ at a time (I'm assuming the $D_i$ are Cartier divisors?).  Note that we have a short exact sequence:
$$0 \to \omega_X \to \omega_X(D_1) \to \omega_{D_1} \to 0.$$
Then do the short exact sequence
$$0 \to \omega_{D_1} \to \omega_{D_1}(D_2|_{D_1}) \to \omega_{D_2|_{D_1}} \to 0.$$
Repeat, and keep track of everything, you'll get the answer you want.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, is this short exact sequence valid for all the scheme? It seems that the short exact sequence comes from tensoring $$0 \to O_X \to O_X(D) \to O_D(D) \to 0$$ by $\omega_X$, and using the adjuction formula for the third term. Here comes two problem:(1)Why it is exact after tensoring $\omega_X$(2)Why adjunction formula can be applied to this case. Could you please point out the reference of this sort to me, because I am not good at birational geometry.

Comment: It doesn't come from there exactly.  The right way to obtain it is from Hom'ing the exact sequence

$$0 \to O_X(-D) \to O_X \to O_D \to 0$$

into $\omega_X$, and noting $Ext^1(O_D, \omega_X) = \omega_D$.  The next Ext vanishes which gives you surjectivity on the right.  There are no other Ext's for obvious reasons (at least as long as $D$ is Cartier).  This isn't birational geometry, it's Grothendieck/Serre-duality theory.  Perhaps you could look at Residues and Duality by Hartshorne?  